# NUnit Running Tests in Parallel

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a test which loops over a List and runs a test! I would like to however make this run in parallel. Is there a way that I could do this? Can I create my List to be parallelizable?

Comment: paste the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured that out! All I had to do is to call AsParallel on my List!

Assume that I have a List of Id's which is of type String and I want to run a test for each of the entry, I can do the following inside my test method!

```
myList.AsParallel.SelectMany(entry =>
{
   // execute the test for each of the entry
   // return entry;
});
```

What I noticed is that the time taken to run all the tests for each element in my List reduced significantly by running them in parallel!

Comment: paste the code and mark is as an answer, maybe someone will find it usefull one day.